# Cannot send multiple attachments from different directories using Send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell

I cannot send multiple attachments using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet, **if those files are in separate directories**. I can send one file, I can send the other, I can send both *If they're in the same directory*, but not if they are in different directories.

The file/folders look like this:

```
C:\Scripts\Folder\test.txt
C:\Scripts\Folder\Logs\log.txt
```

I am specifying these files as attachments by creating an array like so:

```
$attachments = @("C:\Scripts\Folder\test.txt","C:\Scripts\Folder\Logs\log.txt")
```

I'm running PowerShell 5.1 and have tested this on both Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 v1803.

$PSVersionTable on Windows Server 2012 R2:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

$PSVersionTable on Windows 10 1803:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.407
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.407
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Here is the full script to send the message:

```
# Credentials
$username = "user@domain.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password

# Attachments
$attachments = @("C:\Scripts\Folder\test.txt","C:\Scripts\Folder\Logs\log.txt")

Send-MailMessage -To "Recipient <recipient@domain.com>" -Subject "Subject Line" -Body "Body text" -SmtpServer smtp.domain.com -Attachments $attachments -Credential $cred -From "Sender <user@domain.com>" -Port 587 -Priority High -UseSsl
```

There are no error messages produced, and the message is sent and delivered with *the first attachment*. If I remove the first file from the array, the second file (the file in the lower directory) is sent. If I move the second file to the same directory as the first file, both are sent just fine. I have searched high and low for an answer as to why this may be happening but I can't find an answer regarding the issue of multiple directories being sourced for attachments. Nothing is specified in the [help for Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) regarding multiple directories either.

I have tried specifying the attachment files in different ways too. I tried:

1. Adding each file's FullName to its own variable, and made `$attachments` an array of those variables
2. Using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq "test.txt") -or ($_.Name -eq "log.txt")} | Send-MailMessage`

None of these things work unless both files are in the same directory.  Can anyone help explain why that is or show me where I've gone wrong? I know there are plenty of workarounds but I would like to address this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with your code and re-created the same folder/file structure on my Windows 10 Machine and everything works just as expected.
I receive the email and both the attachments are present.

What does your `$PSVersionTable` say your PSVersion of PowerShell is?
Mine is like so:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.134                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.134                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

This is running Windows 10 build 1809
For my test I used my Office 365 account sending through smtp.office365.com.

Comment: Just edited with the output on both systems I've tested on

Comment: Can you please share your code so I can try it as you have? Sanitized of course, I'll input my own creds.

Comment: Everything was the same as yours with the exception of creds and server where I used my own creds and office 365 for SMTP. As a recipient in the To parameter I only added my email though, so no "Recipients" in the parameter, just the one email address without anything else in the string

Comment: Ah, I missed that you said that in the answer. Hmm.. I will do some more testing.